# Detecting Clicks on Google Plus Follow Button (Add To Circle)

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to detect when a user clicks on the Google+ follow button to add us to his circles. [I can't find anything in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/).

[image: Follow Button Google+]

For the +1 button, it's easy you just have to define [`data-callback`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#tag_parameters).

```
<div data-callback="subscribeGooglePlusOne" data-href="https://hackisition.com/" data-size="medium" class="g-plusone"></div>
```

But what's the pattern for the Follow button?

Comment: I think you can add an event and track it in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a feature is not currently supported, if you would like to see it implemented [star this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=674).